# How to inject a bean into CacheErrorHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm on spring framework version 5.3.23, spring boot version 2.7.0

I know I can extend `CachingConfigurerSupport` to provide a `CacheErrorHandler` for handling cache layer errors. However, the interface of the bean creation is:

```
interface CachingConfigurer {
  public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler();
}
```

My problem is: we need to inject some other beans into this `CacheErrorHandler` bean. The interface does not allow me to do that. Is there another way to configure a `CacheErrorHandler` bean with injection? If I simply declare a regular `CacheErrorHandler` bean, would it be automatically discovered by the cache configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question as I figured it out. It's actually quite straightforward.

The crux of the solution is that the methods defined in `CachingConfigurer` do **NOT** have to create the beans. They do not need to be annotated with `@Bean`. They just need to return the bean. The javadoc of `CachingConfigurer` is actually misleading in this aspect as it appears that the `@Bean` annotation is needed.

So what I needed can be easily done by declaring the beans elsewhere and injecting those beans into this `CachingConfigurer`. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager myCacheManager(args) {
      ...
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheErrorHandler myCacheErrorHandler(args) {
      ...
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    private final CacheManager myCacheManager;
    private final CacheErrorHandler myCacheErrorHandler;

    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return myCacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return myCacheErrorHandler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, only get CacheErrorHandler from the CachingConfigurer bean

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically, the previous answer is wrong!

In fact, you can inject other bean dependencies/collaborators into Spring Cache infrastructure components, such as a `CacheErrorHandler` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheErrorHandler.html)) when implementing the `CachingConfigurer` interface ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachingConfigurer.html)), although maybe not in a way you might expect.

I have demonstrated your use case in this [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java).

In summary:

- My [test configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L142-L146) implements the `CachingConfigurer`.
- I [override](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L148-L151) the `errorHandler()` method to return a "custom" `CacheErrorHandler`. Also see the `TestCacheErrorHandler` (custom) implementation, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L205-L217).
- As you can see, the `TestCacheErrorHandler` [requires](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L208-L210) a `Logger`.
- The `Logger` is declared and configured as a [bean in the Spring container](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L153-L156) (`ApplicationContext`).

> NOTE: Now, you could imagine the `Logger` being replaced by a sophisticated management/monitoring service using `Micrometer`, or perhaps a backend database. This was a test and I wanted to minimize the dependencies and complexity to focus on the problem at hand.

- In good Spring fashion, I used [constructor-injection](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L150), as is recommended.

> TIP: The key to this injection (autowiring), is that the bean method for the "mockLogger" bean is "proxied" by Spring (using CGLIB (class-based) proxy (as opposed to interface based proxying JDK Dynamic Proxies)). This allows the actual `mockLogger` bean to be inject and not some arbitrary object. This implicit in the `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotation [declaration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L143-L144), where the `proxyBeanMethods` is by default, set to `true`. If I change this configuration to `proxyBeanMethods` set to `false`, the test will fail, since the `CacheErrorHandler` will get a reference to an unmanaged `Logger`. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html#proxyBeanMethods--) for `@SpringBootConfiguration` for more details.

- The [test case method](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L114-L140) goes on to assert and verify that the proper interactions happen based on the bean invocations.

> NOTE: I used [mock](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L219-L315) Spring Cache infrastructure components to precisely control the `Cache` behavior, such as simulating an error that would necessarily involve custom `CacheErrorHandler` in my test. The mock infrastructure will also allow you to test other caching infrastructure components (such as a custom `CacheResolver`) or caching behaviors in a similar manner.

Ultimately, the test proves and demonstrates that you can inject other dependencies into caching infrastructure components, using preferably constructor injection (which is truly the only Thread-safe way to wire collaborators, especially in a multi-Threaded environment, such as a Web application, providing the `this` reference does not escape during construction of course ;-) ).

As 1 final [test](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L150-L165), I also tested and demonstrated that it is also possible to [declare](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L173-L177) the "custom" `CacheErrorHandler` as a Spring "bean" managed by the Spring container and inject (autowire) [additional dependencies](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L243-L245) (and [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L189-L192)) using (field-based) setter injection (not recommended, but also possible).

The 2 key things in this test case is [this](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L155-L157) and [this](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cache-infra-comp-setter-injection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L159-L164).

If you have additional questions, please post in the comments, but I think the test class is pretty self-explanatory.

Cheers!